# Save arrays from loop in one txt file in columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm creating an array of zeros (587x1) in which I want to replace a zero with a one in a specific line of the array given as an index from another file. This part works fine in my code so far.

Afterwards, I want to save all these newly created arrays in one txt file as columns next to each other, separated by tabs. What my code does, however, is overwriting the arrays. How do I manage to append them next to each other in one file?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Update: I managed to write all the arrays to one file, however, they are now simply printed on top of each other - how do I write them to columns appearing next to each other?

```
import os
import numpy as np
participants = ['001']
for vp in participants:
   with open('file.txt') as f:
      content = f.readlines()
   content = [x.strip() for x in content]
   content = map(int, content)
f = open(outfile.txt, 'w')       
for line in content:
      with open('outfile.txt', 'a') as f:
            arr = np.zeros((587, 1), dtype = int)
            np.put(arr, [line], [1])
            np.savetxt(f, arr, fmt='%i')
f.close()
```

Comment: What is the input of file.txt?

Comment: Try `np.savetxt(f, arr, fmt='%i')`, I was not able to test it, because I don't have the file.txt

Comment: Hi, file.txt only contains numbers referring to the lines in the array (e.g. [224, 368]) where the zeros are supposed to be replaced with ones. Your suggestion doesn't help unfortunately, everything's still overwritten resulting only in the last array in the file 'outfile.txt'

Comment: I would develop code like this in small steps.Like making sure I can write twice to a file with the right overlap. Get the inner most loop working fight first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code, that adds a given `(n,1)` shaped array as a column to a textfile that contains a `(n,m)` shaped matrix of integers:

```
def appendAsColumn(arr):
    fileContent = np.loadtxt('outfile.txt', dtype = int, ndmin = 2)
    fileContent = np.hstack((fileContent, arr.astype(int)))
    np.savetxt('outfile.txt', fileContent, fmt='%i')
```

Note that this will not work for the very first entry of the file, you will need to call

```
np.savetxt('outfile.txt', arr, fmt='%i')
```

for the first column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! I managed to write the file with the columns next to each other. The only problem is that the first column with the first index is now printed twice:                                                                    `f = open('outfile.txt' , 'w')   
firstline = content[0]  
arr = np.zeros((587, 1), dtype = int)  
np.put(arr, [firstline], [1])  
np.savetxt('outfile.txt', arr, fmt='%i')  
line = content[1:]
for line in content:
    arr = np.zeros((587, 1), dtype = int)
    np.put(arr, line, [1])    
    appendAsColumn(arr)`

Comment: Okay, I just fixed it myself. The index to content had to be given at the beginning of the for loop to avoid repetition of the first column. Thanks so much anyway!